# Styling HTML <input> tags

Tags: html, css

I'm making a search bar for my website. I have an input tag and when you type inside it the results come up in small blocks. The results come up fine, but for some reason I can't work out why the styling for my input bar isn't working. I can't adjust the size or position of the bar. Or anything, basically. Here's the related code:

```css
.searchbar{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    left: 50%;
}
#search_cont{
    left: 37.5%;
    position: absolute;
}
#whatIWant{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 37.5%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 15%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='search_cont'><input type='text' ng-model='searchbar' class='.searchbar' placeholder='Search'></div>
<div id='whatIWant'>What I want</div>
```

Here's the full thing in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tobsta/ykmp7bed/

Comment: It not `class='.searchbar'` it be `class='searchbar'`. class name is specified by without dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class name is specified by without dot.

It not `class='.searchbar'` it be `class='searchbar'`.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/obz4tc65/

```css
.searchbar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 50%;
}
#search_cont {
  left: 37.5%;
  position: absolute;
}
#whatIWant {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 37.5%;
  height: 24px;
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='search_cont'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='searchbar' class='searchbar' placeholder='Search'>
</div>
<div id='whatIWant'>What I want</div>
```

Comment: That mistake of mine was so dumb!

Comment: It still doesn't allow me to change the width. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Actually it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

-Name of class should be without . (dot) 
-Your search bar is inside  this division. Apply width to this division like this. And then you can apply width on search bar and style it.

```css
#search_cont{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

Hope you have this problem. You can style your search bar now by giving margin, height and width to .searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

You just entered a dot in your class field.

You should use class='searchbar'

```
<input type='text' ng-model='searchbar' class='searchbar' placeholder='Search'>
```